# Noisy Signal in Data (FFT) - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filtering, noise

I am plotting some data I collected at 10000 Hz, I attached a snip of some of the data in the form of an FFT and time. I am getting a repeating frequency around 10Hz that seems to be pretty obviously some sort of noise from the system i am testing. The signal shows up in the time domain and also the frequency domain.

I am looking to use MATLAB to remove these spikes.

Has anyone dealt with a similar issue and can provide any advice.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out specific frequency components of a signal, you would normally use either a notch filter or a comb filter, for which MATLAB already has some commands in the DSP System Toolbox:

- https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/iirnotch.html
- https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/fdesign.comb.html

Alternatively, if you have the Signal Processing Toolbox, you can use the band-stop Butterworth filter to remove individual frequency components (ranges) using

- https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html